# Как можно видеть причину удаления вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение

Сегодня увидел, что был удалён вопрос, где на ответ я потратил достаточно времени, да и был он весьма полезен в таких ситуациях. А как можно увидеть причину удаления?
До этого (месяц назад) на нём же мне кто-то поставил минус с рекомендацией удалить, но на призыв прокомментировать ответа не было. Автор вопроса поставил плюс тогда же.
Жаль не 10 баллов, разумеется, а потраченного времени. Это не был вопрос из серии "как мне напечатать три запятые? Не знаю питон."

(Конкретный вопрос: "Может ли нейросеть стабильно сходиться на обучаемых значениях, и не сходиться на тестовых?")

Comment: свои удаленные вопросы/ответы видны всегда. Чужие - видны пользователям с репутаций 10000

Comment: [Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1403298/1365) удален Духом сообщества: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd0Uj.png . Значит был удален автоматически как закрытый и с нулевым рейтингом вопроса и ответа.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо. 1) Это нормальная практика - удаляются все вопросы с нулевым рейтингом вопроса и ответа? 2) Предельный случай - заходит Дух на страницу с +1 за вопрос и +1 за ответ, минусует оба и удаляет:-) Так сработает?

Comment: 1 - видимо да, точных правил я не знаю. 2 - Дух - это бот, он не минусует

Comment: P.S. 1 - вот нашел в справке: [Почему Дух сообщества удалил мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), конкретно читать начиная с "Если вопрос был закрыт более 9 дней назад и ..." Вопрос закрыт 13 мая, как раз 9 дней прошло.

Comment: @insolor, а почему вы думаете, что Дух - это бот? Я вот, когда проверяю вопросы, нажимаю, какой дать комментарий ("вопрос слишком общий" и т.д.), и задавший вопрос видит ответ от Духа. Но я же не бот.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо. Тогда ясно, почему удалён. А не скажете, почему тогда он был закрыт? (ясно с тем, что бот не минусует, спасибо. Можно, значит, самому заминусовать, а бот уже автоматически всё удалит).

Comment: Дух - это специальный пользователь, который указывается в автоматических действиях. Фактически - бот. Собственной волей он не обладает. См. описание пользователя: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1 (да, там написано, что он минусует, но по факту минус возникает при простановке тревоги конкретным участником, а не сам по себе)

Comment: Причина закрытия: `"Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей."` Без кода воспроизвести ситуацию, описанную в вопросе, возможно только с нуля реализовав свою такую же сеть и обучив на каких-то данных. Ну или пытаться угадать. Вероятность угадать конечно не нулевая, но уже поздно.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, ясно, т.е. кто-то выставил тревогу, а затем бот закрыл. И прекрасная причина закрытия. Нейросеть - это не просто код. А системное мышление для того и есть, чтобы можно было давать общие рекомендации по устранению проблем, а не только "замени + на - в строке 5". Считаю, что такие общие рекомендации в разы полезнее для базы знаний, чем инструкции школьнику заменить конкретный + на -.  Но да, если большинство предпочитает давать советы только на уровне конкретных кодов, то вопросы без кодов будут закрываться. Для меня вывод простой - тратить меньше времени на глубокие ответы.

Comment: Да никто не ставил там тревогу, не занимайтесь выдумыванием теорий заговоров и каких-то сложных схем. Если кому-то нужно было поставить минус, достаточно было просто поставить минус. `Для меня вывод простой - тратить меньше времени на глубокие ответы.` - просто не нужно так уж привязываться к ответам, это не стоит того. У меня за 11 лет куча удаленных ответов, есть несправедливо заминусованный даже (по моему мнению, конечно же), если из-за каждого ответа так переживать - никаких нервов не хватит.

Comment: 1) Тогда я что-то не понимаю. Если тревоги не было, то бот увидел, что нет кода, и закрыл, так как рейтинг был 0?? Вопросы же там были вполне нормальные с указанием желаемого поведения. Очень странно, тут куча вопросов без кода.
2) Там стоял запрос на удаление моего ответа вскоре после моего ответа. Это не тревога?

Comment: 1 - Вопрос закрыт обычными участниками (5 человек) по результатам проверки через очередь проверки, не ботом. Через 9 дней после закрытия удален ботом. 2 - запрос на удаление - это не тревога. Только тревога - это тревога.

Comment: 1.5 -  `Очень странно, тут куча вопросов без кода.` - жизнь вообще несправедливая штука.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. 5 неведомых мне человек решили, что общие ответы не нужны. И да, справедливости не требую, просто хотел разобраться, чтобы понимать, как дальше действовать. Большое спасибо за подробные ответы!

Comment: @Сергей закрыли вопрос, а не ваш ответ. Каждый день какие-то случайные люди закрывают десятки вопросов. `5 неведомых мне человек решили` - вы бы предпочли, чтобы это были 5 известных вам людей?) Что бы это изменило?)

Comment: Я бы спросил каждого о ходе его или её мыслей, и сам стал бы мудрее. (Хороший был вопрос).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136520/discussion-between--and-insolor).

Comment: Не вижу смысла. Вопрос восстановлен, ситуация исчерпана.